# Get timezone with continent and city in Android (e.g. Asia/Seoul)

Tags: android, date, timezone

I want to get the continent and city of the default `Timezone` in Android.
I have tried using `getDefault().getDisplayName()` on the `Timezone` class but the string it returns isn't what I want (which is Asia/Seoul). Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.
Simply use `getId()` on the `Timezone` class.

Comment: For anyone using the modern `ZoneId` class, the answer is similar: `ZoneId.systemDefault().getId()`. In both cases I believe there is no guarantee that the returned ID string will be of the form area/city, though for most JVMs it will.

Comment: Exactly, for me it returns GMT, UTC etc, any way to force it to return geographical regions?